# Is there a tool to generate documents for HELM Charts?

Tags: linux, open-source

I am creating HELM charts to deploy set of applications. I would like to provide documents to help users understand how to configure/understand the parameters mentioned in the values.yaml file in the HELM charts. Is there a tool support to generate documentation from the values.yaml file ? I was hoping to provide comments in the yaml file and then to export these comments as documents.

Example values.yaml file : https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/elastic-stack/values.yaml

```
logstash: #logstash
  enabled: true  #enabled: To enable logstash. Default value: false
  elasticsearch:
    host: elastic-stack-elasticsearch-client #host: DNS pointing to elastic search
```

Expected Output :

```
logstash:
  enabled: To enable logstash. 
         Default value: false
  host: DNS pointing to elastic search
```

I browsed through https://helm.sh/docs/, but was unable to find any support for the usecase I am looking for.

Comment: Can you code? This would be simple enough in Python

Comment: Yes. I was assuming this is a generic usecase and there is something available today. :) Building something on top of ruamel.yaml seems to be a better option. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255885/save-dump-a-yaml-file-with-comments-in-pyyaml/27103244